# Binding background color via MvxColorValueConverter

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind background color to the TextView in the item of the MvxLinearLayout.

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_item" />
```

In the item activity I bind TextView background via MvxColorValueConverter and it doesn't show any background color

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="156"
            local:MvxBind="background Value, Converter=ItemValueColor" />
```

but I can bind TextColor to the same TextView and it will work

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="156"
                local:MvxBind="TextColor Value, Converter=ItemValueColor" />
```

Code of the MvxColorValueConverter

```
public class ItemValueColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter
{
    protected override MvxColor Convert(object value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var intVal = value as int?;

        if (intVal == null)
            return (new MvxColor(0, 0, 0, 150));

        switch (intVal.Value)
        {
            case -1:
                return (new MvxColor(255, 0, 0, 150));
            case 0:
                return (new MvxColor(0, 0, 0, 150));
            case 1:
                return (new MvxColor(0, 255, 0, 150));
        }
        return (new MvxColor(0, 0, 0, 150));
    }
}
```

Am I using right converter? Is it problem in MvxLinearLayout?

Comment: Try using BackgroundColor - like in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ValueConversion/ValueConversion.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/View_Colors.axml#L40

Comment: Thanx Stuart, worked like a charm ;)